# Problema al pasar de XML a PDF con Aspose.pdf JAVA

Tags: java, xml, pdf, class

Estoy creando una clase para que me cree un PDF a través de un XML.
Todo ello lo necesito hacer con Aspose.pdf.
He importado las librerías necesarias e incluido en el pom.xml el repositorio y la dependencia correspondiente.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
        <name>Aspose Java API</name>
        <url>http://artifact.aspose.com/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Importo aspose.pdf.* y me lo da como válido, ningún fallo.
Cuando creo un objeto de la clase Pdf(clase de aspose.pdf.*) no me da tampoco ningún fallo, y es hasta que intento hacer maven install cuando me dice:

`javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: CORBA TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK 9998 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe`

La clase en la que lo estoy intentando hacer es esta, como véis, un método bastante sencillo:

```
package com.telefonica.pleyade.proveedores.ejb.negocio;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import com.t.pl.pr.c.ejb.s.n.IProcesaDocumentoBeanLocal;
import com.t.pl.pr.c.ejb.s.n.IProcesaDocumentoBeanRemote;
import com.t.pl.pr.c.ejb.s.n.IProcesaDocumentoServicio;
import com.t.pl.pr.m.au.ProveedorAuxiliar;

import aspose.pdf.*;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Local(IProcesaDocumentoBeanLocal.class)
@Remote(IProcesaDocumentoBeanRemote.class)
public class GenerarPDF implements IProcesaDocumentoServicio{

    @Override
    public byte[] crearCertificado(ProveedorAuxiliar idProveedor){

        String dataDir = "C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/";

        Pdf pdf = new Pdf();

        pdf.bindXML(dataDir + "plantillaXML.xml", null);

        //Para guardar el archivo se puede hacer con:
        pdf.save(dataDir + idProveedor + ".pdf");

        return pdf.getBuffer();
    }

}
```

Comment: hola @Richard . Puedes por favor añadir más parte del mensaje que te da Maven?? 

Si no te da más, puedes ejecutar "mvn -x install" ??? así hará debug (con el -X y tendremos más datos)

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Me sale también este error:

`Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: aspose/pdf/Pdf`