# ¿Cómo generar un archivo PDF en Java sin utilizar FO/XSL?

Tags: java, pdf

Quería saber como generar un archivo PDF en Java a partir de un XML sin tener que utilizar FO/XSL. He probado a pasar un informe PDF de ejemplo a XML por medio de una página en línea, y así utilizar ese ejemplo de XML para convertirlo a PDF en Java sin tener que utilizar de por medio FO/XSL ¿Habría alguna manera de hacer esto sin tener que utilizar FO/XSL?

Un saludo

Comment: ya intentaste con [aspose-pdf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195710/problema-al-pasar-de-xml-a-pdf-con-aspose-pdf-java)?

Comment: Hola, lo estoy intentando ahora mismo, he añadido la dependencia en pom.xml, pero me da este error de compilación: Missing artifact com.aspose:aspose-pdf:jar:2.9.0. Justo en esta línea que señalo a continuación en negrita:
  **<dependency>**
   <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.0</version>
  </dependency>

¿Qué versión tendría que instalar? ¿Y en que parte del archivo pom.xml?

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya he conseguido solucionar lo del error de la dependencia en tiempo de compilación

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.